# How to remove expiration header from apache

Tags: apache

I have been using the apache mod expiration module for setting an expiration HTTP header (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_expires.html). This module set an expiration header in all server responses.

I want to remove the expiration date for all the redirect 302. Is there a way to remove the expiration header for 302 redirects.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by the below code.

Header unset Expires "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} == 302"